# How to get date when click edit data

Tags: angular

tempData['harilibur_start'] = new Date(data.data.harilibur_start).toString().split('T')[0]; tempData['harilibur_end'] = new Date(data.data.harilibur_end).toString().split('T')[0];

Answer (score 1):

- First

When you use new Date, it will return the string of Date with format:

```
Tue Aug 18 2020 16:12:24 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
```

You can't split('T') like that.

- Second

When you click on a button , you need define a function on component.ts file (e.g test.component.ts). In this function, you will get data which passed and call new Data function.
On HTML

```
<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
```

In component.ts:

```
export class TestComponent {
  clickMessage = '';

  onClickMe(data) {
    newDate = new Date(data).toString();
  }
}
```

If the data you pass to new Date() function have format like this:

```
2015-03-25T12:00:00Z
```

You have to change your code to:

```
tempData['harilibur_start'] = new Date(data.data.harilibur_start.toString().split('T')[0]).toString(); 

tempData['harilibur_end'] = new Date(data.data.harilibur_end.toString().split('T')[0]).toString();
```